# Call virtual function from another subclass

Tags: c++, function, virtual, subclass, abstract

I've been set an assignment to create an rpn calculator that takes infix notation as input. So part of it is that it has to print out different stages of the process. So first it should separate a string into tokens and then store in a vector. Then it should convert this to rpn notation (e.g 3+4  ->  3 4 +) which is the part im stuck on now the part I'm stuck on now.

I've been recommended to use virtual abstract functions for this.  So first I create a class with the abstract function. Then I create a subclass which converts a string to tokens stored in a string vector, this part works fine. Then I should create another subclass which converts the input string to rpn notation, therefore I have to call the function to convert to tokens at the start of this sub-class, this is the bit which I think is going wrong.

I have been given some code as a template and so far it's been very buggy so there might be something wrong with the syntax where the error is.

So I have this as my main class

`template<typename T>
  class tokenstream {
    public:
        virtual bool process(const std::string& input, std::vector<T>& output) = 0;
};`

Then this as the first subclass

```
 class tokenifier: public tokenstream<std::string> {
public:
    bool process(const std::string& input, std::vector<std::string>& output) {
        //this part works fine, ive tested it. 
};
```

So then I have to create another subclass and then call the above function inside it, this is the part where it goes wrong.

```
class infix2rpn: public tokenstream<std::string> {
private:
    tokenifier *tokens;
public:
    tokenifier(tokenstream *_tokens): tokens(_tokens) {} //I think this line is the problem
    bool process(const std::string& input, std::vector<std::string>& output) {
        //call the underlying tokenstream object
        std::vector<std::string> infixtokens;
        if(!tokens->process(input, infixtokens))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return shunting_yard(infixtokens, output);
    }
    bool shunting_yard(const std::vector<std::string>& input, std::vector<std::string>& output){
       //i've tested the shunting_yard algorithm and it works fine
    }
};
```

When I try to compile it I get the error "ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'tokenifier' with no type [-fpermissive].

So the part I don't understand is how to call other virtual functions from another subclass.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class is called `infix2rpn`, so its constructor should be named `infix2rpn` as well, not `tokenifier`. This has nothing to do with virtual functions.

Moreover, your attribute should be a `tokenstream<std::string>*`, not a `tokenifier*`, because you can't convert the `tokenstream<std::string>*` you get in the constructor to a `tokenifier*`.

Answer (score 0):

```
tokenifier(tokenstream *_tokens): tokens(_tokens) {}
```

This was probably meant to be constructor, but in that case, the name of the method should be `infix2rpn`, same as the class name.
The error means, that you specified method `tokenifier` that has not specified return type, only constructors and destructors have no return type.

Note that `void` also specification of return type, in that case it means nothing returned.